# how to use over 5gb data in access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I got new project in Access DB. Huge text data will have to import weekly but problem is, it will grow over 5-6 GB day after day what is right way to use such type of data in MS Access 2013.

Thanks,
Mir

Comment: I think you need a real dbms. SQL server if you're using Microsoft.

Comment: That volume of data is definitely not appropriate for Access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQl server  Express an still use acces as a front-end. Storage is only one problem though. What about reporting and business intelligence? Access is a good reporting tool but it can't do it all. Will you need Big Data type analysis?

Comment: Yes, I need big data type analysis.